# How to show node with multiple related term with it through view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using drupal 6 and I've Taxonomy Structure like below

```
Gender (Vocabulary)
   Men's (Term)
   Women's (Term)

Movement (Vocabulary)
   Automatic (Term)
   Digital (Term)
```

Both vocabulary are attached to a content type, so that i can choose men's/women's and automatic/digital.

Now i want to show all the nodes of this content type with their related terms as a separate column in view page display. For that i chose Taxonomy: Term under the groups Taxonomy to create a field in view to display them.

But its repeating single term for both column as you can see in below image. In exposed filter these vocabulary working fine because i had an option to choose which vocabulary i want to select to create a filter but this option is not there in field level creation.

[image]

But i want to show them like this

[image]

Also you can see in very last column that show Digital,Men's indicate that two different term are related to this node.

Can anyone point me to the right direction to accomplish this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could identify what your fields are in the table.  The first two appear to be terms from a vocabulary, but I'm not sure what u\you used on the last one.  Please tell us what you selected from the list of content options for each field.

Comment: @Ashlar As you can see red color text that specify (Taxonomy:Term) for first two and (Taxonomy:Vacabulary Name) for very last column. I don't have option to choose which term i want to use when i'm adding (Taxonomy:Term) as a field.

Comment: Views can be complicated with many options.  I cannot duplicate your setup with the information provided.  I need the specific setup you have used to help.  Please provide the type of view you created (content, term, etc) on the initial view definition page.  Then identify the option you picked to identify each field. Also, did you change the name of the columns in the table, or are these the column names that views used? Finally, what filters and arguments are used, if any?